# D3.js : Updating data on chart not working

Tags: d3.js

Continuing to try and master the enter-update-exit pattern...

I've got a relatively simple reusable d3.js chart, and I want to be able to update the chart between two data sets. I'm getting close, but the chart is not updating properly.

**You can see a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rolfsf/vba6n4sh/2/**

**Where did I mess up the enter-update-exit pattern?**

The chart code looks like this:

```
function relativeSizeChart() {
var width = 1200,
    margin = 0,
    padding = 16,
    r = d3.scale.linear(),

    onTotalMouseOver = null,
    onTotalClick = null,
    onClusterMouseOver = null,
    onClusterClick = null,

    val = function(d){return d;};
    totalFormat = function(d){return d;};
    clusterFormat = function(d){return d;};
    clusterFormat2 = function(d){return d;};

function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {
        //console.log(data);

        var clusterCount = data.Clusters.length,
            totalColWidth = 0.3*width,
            colWidth = (width - totalColWidth)/clusterCount,
            height = colWidth + 2*padding,
            maxRadius = (colWidth - 10)/2;


        var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg")
                    .data([data]);

        var svgEnter = svg
                .enter().append("svg")
                    .attr('class', function(d){
                        if( onTotalMouseOver !== null || onTotalClick !== null ||onClusterMouseOver !== null || onClusterClick !== null){
                            return 'clickable';
                        }else{
                            return 'static';
                        }
                    })
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height);

        var background, clusterLines;

            background = svgEnter.append("g")
                    .attr('class', 'background');

        var headers = svgEnter.append("g")
                    .attr('class', 'headers')
                    .selectAll("text.header")
                    .data(data.Headers, function(d){return d;});

        var total = svgEnter.append("g")
                    .attr('class', 'total');

        var cluster = svgEnter.selectAll('g.cluster')
                    .data(data.Clusters,function(d){ return d;});

        var clusterEnter = cluster 
                .enter().append("g")
                    .attr('class', 'cluster')
                    .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
                        return 'translate(' + (totalColWidth + i*colWidth) + ',0)';
                    });

        var clusters = svg.selectAll('g.cluster');

        r = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(data.Clusters, function(d){return d[1];})])
                    .range([40, maxRadius]);           

        background  .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "chart-bg")
                    .attr('x', 0)
                    .attr('y', padding)
                    .attr('height', (height-padding))
                    .attr('width', width)
                    .attr('class', 'chart-bg');

        background  .append("g")
                    .attr('class', 'cluster-lines');

        background  .append("line")
                    .attr("class", "centerline")
                    .attr('x1', (totalColWidth - padding))
                    .attr('x2', width - (colWidth/2))
                    .attr('y1', (height+padding)/2)
                    .attr('y2', (height+padding)/2);

        clusterLines = background.select('g.cluster-lines')
                    .selectAll("line")
                    .data(data.Clusters,function(d){ return d;})
                    .enter().append('line')
                    .attr('class', 'cluster-line');

        headers     .enter().append('text')
                    .attr('class', 'header');

        total       .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "total-cluster")
                    .attr('x', padding)
                    .attr('y', 0.2*(height+(4*padding)))
                    .attr('height', 0.5*(height))
                    .attr('width', totalColWidth-(2*padding))
                    .attr('rx', 4)
                    .attr('ry', 4)
                    .on('mouseover', onTotalMouseOver)
                    .on('click', onTotalClick);

        total       .append("text")
                    .attr("class", "total-name")
                    .attr('x', totalColWidth/2 )
                    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return ((height+padding)/2) + (padding + 10); });

        total       .append("text")
                    .attr("class", "total-value")
                    .attr('x', totalColWidth/2 )
                    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return ((height+padding)/2); })
                    .text(totalFormat(0));

        clusterEnter.append('circle')
                    .attr('class', 'bubble')
                    .attr('cx', function(d, i) { return colWidth/2; })
                    .attr('cy', function(d, i) { return (height+padding)/2;})
                    .attr("r", "50")
                    .on('mouseover', function(d, i, j) {
                        if (onClusterMouseOver != null) onClusterMouseOver(d, i, j);
                    })
                    .on('mouseout', function() { /*do something*/ })
                    .on('click', function(d, i){ 
                        onClusterClick(this, d, i); 
                    });  


        clusterEnter.append('text')
                    .attr('class', 'cluster-value')
                    .attr('x', function(d, i) { return colWidth/2; })
                    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return ((height+padding)/2); })
                    .text(clusterFormat(0)); 


        clusterEnter.append('text')
                    .attr('class', 'cluster-value-2')
                    .attr('x', function(d, i) { return colWidth/2; })
                    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return ((height+padding)/2) + (padding + 10); })
                    .text(clusterFormat2(0));

        //update attributes
        clusterLines.attr('x1', function(d, i) { return totalColWidth + i*colWidth })
                    .attr('x2', function(d, i) { return totalColWidth + i*colWidth })
                    .attr('y1', function(d, i) { return padding })
                    .attr('y2', function(d, i) { return (height); });

        headers     .attr('x', function(d, i) { 
                        if(i === 0){
                            return (totalColWidth/2);
                        }else{
                            return (totalColWidth + (i*colWidth) - (colWidth/2))
                        }
                    })
                    .attr('y', 12);

       //clean up old 
        svg          .exit().remove();

        cluster      .exit().selectAll('circle.bubble')
                     .style("opacity", 1)
                     .style("fill", "#DDD")
                     .style("stroke", "#DDD")
                     .transition()
                     .duration(500)
                     .style("opacity", 0);

        cluster      .exit().remove();
        headers      .exit().remove();

        function update(data) {

            //update with data
            svg         .selectAll('text.total-value')
                        .transition()
                        .delay(400)
                        .duration(1000)
                        .tween( 'text', function(d, i) {
                            var currentValue = +this.textContent.replace(/\D/g,''); 
                            var interpolator = d3.interpolateRound( currentValue, d.Total[1] );
                            return function( t ) {
                                this.textContent = totalFormat(interpolator(t));
                            };
                        });  

            svg         .selectAll('text.total-name')
                        .text(val(data.Total[0]));

            svg         .selectAll('circle')
                        .attr('class', function(d, i) { 
                            if(d[1] === 0){ return 'bubble empty';}
                            else {return 'bubble';}
                        })
                        .transition()
                        .duration(1000)
                        .delay(function(d, i) { return 500 + (i * 100); })
                        .ease('elastic')   
                        .attr("r", function (d, i) { return r(d[1]); });

            svg         .selectAll('text.cluster-value')
                        .transition()
                        .delay(function(d, i) { return 500 + (i * 100); })
                        .duration(1000)
                        .tween( 'text', function(d, i) {
                            var currentValue = +this.textContent.replace(/\D/g,'');
                            var interpolator = d3.interpolateRound( currentValue, d[1] );
                            return function( t ) {
                                this.textContent = clusterFormat(interpolator(t));
                            };
                        });  


            svg         .selectAll('text.cluster-value-2')
                        .transition()
                        .delay(function(d, i) { return 500 + (i * 100); })
                        .duration(1000)
                        .tween( 'text', function(d, i) {
                            var currentValue = +this.textContent.replace(/\D/g,'');
                            var interpolator = d3.interpolateRound( currentValue, d[0] );
                            return function( t ) {
                                this.textContent = clusterFormat2(interpolator(t));
                            };
                        });  

            headers     .text(function(d, i){return d});
        }

        update(data);

    });


}

chart.totalFormat = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return totalFormat;
    totalFormat = _;
    return chart;
};
chart.clusterFormat = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return clusterFormat;
    clusterFormat = _;
    return chart;
};
chart.clusterFormat2 = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return clusterFormat2;
    clusterFormat2 = _;
    return chart;
};



chart.width = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = _;
    return chart;
};
chart.onTotalClick = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return onTotalClick;
    onTotalClick = _;
    return chart;
};

chart.onTotalMouseOver = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return onTotalMouseOver;
    onTotalMouseOver = _;
    return chart;
};

chart.onClusterClick = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return onClusterClick;
    onClusterClick = _;
    return chart;
};

chart.onClusterMouseOver = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return onClusterMouseOver;
    onClusterMouseOver = _;
    return chart;
};


return chart;
}
```

my sample data looks like this

```
var data = {
"data1": {
    Headers: ["Total", "Col 1A", "Col 2A", "Col 3A", "Col 4A"],
    Total: ["Total # of Widgets", 1200],
    Clusters: [
        [100, 1200],
        [67, 800],
        [42, 500],
        [17, 198]
    ]
},
"data2": {
    Headers: ["Total", "Col 1B", "Col 2B", "Col 3B", "Col 4B"],
    Total: ["Total # of Widgets", 1200],
    Clusters: [
        [20, 245],
        [31, 371],
        [32, 386],
        [12, 145]
    ]
}
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your enter/update/exit pattern:

```
        background = svgEnter.append("g")
                .attr('class', 'background');

    var headers = svgEnter.append("g")
                .attr('class', 'headers')
                .selectAll("text.header")
                .data(data.Headers, function(d){return d;});

    var total = svgEnter.append("g")
                .attr('class', 'total');
```

This code is referencing `svgEnter`, which is OK the first time through, as `svgEnter` has a non-empty selection (it contains the svg you create a little earlier).

On subsequent calls to this function, `svgEnter` will contain an empty selection, as the svg element already exists.  So, I have modified this part of your code to:

```
        svgEnter.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'background');
        var background = svg.selectAll('g.background');

        svgEnter.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'headers')

        var headers = svg.selectAll('g.headers').selectAll('text.header')
                         .data(data.Headers, function(d) { return d; });            
        svgEnter.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'total');

        var total = svg.selectAll('g.total');
```

This will create the `g` elements if we also have to create the `svg` element.  It will then create the variables similar to your existing code using selections from the `svg` element.

I think that they're the only changes I made, the rest of your code works as expected.

An updated fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/vba6n4sh/9/

Comment: Thanks Ben!  So, basically... I want to append elements to the svgEnter variable, and then use the svg variable for selections?

Comment: In this particular case, yes.  The first time you run through that code, everything works OK, because nothing exists yet.  The second (and third, etc) time through because the elements already exist, the `enter()` selections will be empty.  This means that your subsequent operations on the `background`, `total` and `headers` objects (which in your code utilised the `svgEnter` variable, ie. the `enter()` selection of the `svg`, which is empty since the `svg` already exists) will be operating on an empty selection, so they will never be updated.

Comment: I notice in the updated fiddle, it's creating multiple backgrounds, so I still have a few things to fix, but hopefully the pattern you pointed out will guide me.

Comment: Yep, I see what's happening there.  My advice would be to split the "creation" code out from the "update" code.  In the `chart(selection)` function, call a "create" function only on the first run through, which creates all those elements that aren't directly bound to your data.  Then in the chart function, you can just worrying about any elements that are bound to data.